# How can I implement a rolling function partitioned over another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that looks like

```
 CustomerID         InvoiceDate
       <fctr>              <dttm>
 1      13313 2011-01-04 10:00:00
 2      18097 2011-01-04 10:22:00
 3      16656 2011-01-04 10:23:00
 4      16875 2011-01-04 10:37:00
 5      13094 2011-01-04 10:37:00
 6      17315 2011-01-04 10:38:00
 7      16255 2011-01-04 11:30:00
 8      14606 2011-01-04 11:34:00
 9      13319 2011-01-04 11:40:00
10      16282 2011-01-04 11:42:00
```

It tells me when a person make a transaction.  I would like to know the time between transactions for each customer, preferably in days.  I do this in the following way

```
d <- data %>%
    arrange(CustomerID,InvoiceDate) %>%
    group_by(CustomerID) %>%
    mutate(delta.t = InvoiceDate - lag(InvoiceDate), #calculating the difference
           delta.day = as.numeric(delta.t, unit = 'days'))  %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    arrange(CustomerID) %>%
    inner_join(Ntrans) %>% #Existing data.frame telling me the number of transactions per customer
    filter(N>=10) %>% #only want people with more than 10 transactions
    select(-N)
```

However, the result doesn't make sense (seen below)

```
 CustomerID         InvoiceDate    delta.t delta.day
       <fctr>              <dttm>     <time>     <dbl>
 1      12415 2011-01-10 09:58:00  5686 days      5686
 2      12415 2011-02-15 09:52:00 51834 days     51834
 3      12415 2011-03-03 10:59:00 23107 days     23107
 4      12415 2011-04-01 14:28:00 41969 days     41969
 5      12415 2011-05-17 15:42:00 66314 days     66314
 6      12415 2011-05-20 14:13:00  4231 days      4231
 7      12415 2011-06-15 13:37:00 37404 days     37404
 8      12415 2011-07-13 15:30:00 40433 days     40433
 9      12415 2011-07-13 15:31:00     1 days         1
10      12415 2011-07-19 10:51:00  8360 days      8360
```

The differences measured in days are way off.  What I want is something close to SQL's rolling window function partitioned over customerID.  How can I implement this?

Comment: It seems that delta.t is giving results in minutes rather than days. See the difference in rows 8 and 9.

Comment: Oh, that is so weird.

Comment: delta.t works well for me when the class of InvoiceDate is POSIXct

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the difference to days you can use the package lubridate.

```
  > library('lubridate')
> library('dplyr')
> 
> InvoiceDate  <- c('2011-01-10 09:58:00', '2011-02-15 09:52:00', '2011-03-03 10:59:00')
> CustomerID   <- c(111, 111, 111)
> 
> dat <- data.frame('Invo' = InvoiceDate, 'ID' = CustomerID)
> 
> dat %>% mutate('Delta' = as_date(Invo) - as_date(lag(Invo)))
                 Invo  ID   Delta
1 2011-01-10 09:58:00 111 NA days
2 2011-02-15 09:52:00 111 36 days
3 2011-03-03 10:59:00 111 16 days
```